# Pulling values from a picker and converting to an int

Tags: iphone, objective-c, picker

I am trying to make a calculating app that consists of a 2-column picker. The left side of the picker are data values and the data values are being pulled from a plist with the price of each item. The other side of the picker is a string going from 1 to 64.

I'm trying to figure out how to take the string values of both parts of the picker and convert them into an int (so they can be multiplied and printed out)

Here's my code (in its entirety)

```
    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *plistPath =[bundle pathForResource:@"worthList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
self.dataValues = dictionary;
[dictionary release];

NSArray *components = [self.dataValues allKeys];
NSArray *sorted = [components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

self.values = sorted;

NSMutableArray *number =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int x = 1; x < 65; x++)
{
    NSString * numberString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",x];

    [number addObject:numberString];
}
self.quantity = number;
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.doublePicker = nil;
    self.dataValues = nil;
    self.values = nil;
    self.quantity = nil;
    [self setDoublePicker:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

 - (IBAction)calculateItem:(id)sender 
{

NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[message release];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma Picker data source methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
   return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *) pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == kValueComponent)
{
    return [self.values count];
}
return [self.quantity count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:   (NSInteger)component
{
if (component == kValueComponent)
    {
      return [self.values objectAtIndex:row];
    }
return [self.quantity objectAtIndex:row];

}
@end
```

Comment: What are you looking for convert NSString into int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
     NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pickerArr objectAtIndex:row]];
     int test=[str intValue];
```

Comment: Would I stick this in my calculateItem (button action method) or in one of the picker methods?

Comment: put this in picker delegate method:-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

Answer (score 1):

Try this to convert your data string into an int and then do the calculation:

```
int = [yourString intValue];
```

Comment: i tried that and I got a SIGABRT with this as the error message: 2012-03-01 01:13:54.733 mineCalc[946:b303] -[__NSArrayI intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a9fe00
2012-03-01 01:13:54.737 mineCalc[946:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a9fe00'

Comment: If Shweta's post doesn't resolve it then post some code snippet to help you debug this.

Comment: You need to index into the array using objectAtIndex: and pull out the value first. So use the row index of the picker to index into the NSArray before using intValue to covert.

Comment: In your case you are converting an array, try [array objectatindex:i] intValue];

Answer (score 0):

HERE MINUTES AND SECONDS ARE ARRAY.

Delegate method of a picker.
You can use other delegate methods also.

Seconds and minutes are the array which loads the picker in your case use array which is feeded with plist.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (component) {
        case 0:

               minuteTime =[minutes objectAtIndex:row] intValue]; 
            break;

        case 1:
            secondTime = [[seconds objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
            break;
    }
}
```

You can also use this method to distinguish strings further.

```
NSArray *greenTime = [yourstring componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSLog(@"Green Time : %@\nFirst : %@\nSecond : %@",greenTime,[greenTime objectAtIndex:0],[greenTime objectAtIndex:1]);
```